# Is there paid family leave if you start a new job AFTER having a baby?

Tags: united-states, leave, family, new-york

In New York, if one were to start a job right after having a baby (at a place with enough employees to qualify) would they be able to get paid family leave after working for a few months, or is there no option of leave if you start post baby?

Comment: A quick look online says "Full-time employees: Employees who work a regular schedule of 20 or more hours per week are eligible after 26 consecutive weeks of employment." so I guess no? https://paidfamilyleave.ny.gov/eligibility

Comment: ...unless by a few months you mean 6.

Comment: So if you have a baby and then work six months you get leave?

Comment: This question should *not* be closed; this is a matter of state employment law and thus something managers, HR professionals, etc. would be able to answer. OP is not seeking legal advice about a specific issue they are facing; this is a general, hypothetical situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mothers and fathers, including same-sex parents, can take
> job-protected, paid time off to bond with their newborn within the
> first 12 months of the child’s birth.

https://paidfamilyleave.ny.gov/bonding-leave-birth-child

> Covered employees become eligible to take Paid Family Leave for a
> qualifying event once they have met the minimum time-worked
> requirements:
>
> Full-time employees: Employees who work a regular schedule of 20 or
> more hours per week are eligible after 26 consecutive weeks of
> employment.

https://paidfamilyleave.ny.gov/eligibility

So, work for 26 consecutive weeks. Then, if it is still within 12 months of the child's birth, you could be entitled to paid family leave.

Don't forget to notify your employer at least 30 days before the start of leave. And make sure to fill out and submit all the appropriate forms.

Answer (score 5):

Familiarize yourself with the New York Paid Family Leave act (https://paidfamilyleave.ny.gov/). If you qualify, you can take birth of child leave within 12 months of the child's birth. You'll need 26 weeks in at the new job and to give 30 days notice, plus other details as described in the Web site around the act.